# Jenkins pipeline script: Accept merge request from Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, cicd

Is there any other way to accept MR from Jenkins pipeline code ?

I tried to use [this plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/#plugin-content-accept-merge-request) but I always end up receiving: 405 Method Not Allowed.

This is the first time I post here so there could be some mistakes. If you need any further information please let me know

Many thanks !

I'm pretty sure my connection and credential configurations to Gitlab are correct since I'm able to checkout, webhook trigger, ...